# Xamarin iOS Controller Custom Inheritance Issues with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, ios, inheritance, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm having a glitch with a controller that inherits from a base class.  My base looks like:

```
public abstract class BaseUIViewController : UIViewController
{
   public BaseUIViewController() : base() { }

   public BaseUIViewController(..) : base(..) { }
}
```

My controller inherits from this and defines a constructor like:

```
public class MyController : BaseUIViewController
{

   public MyController(ISOmeService service, IOtherService service)
   {
      ..
   }

    override ViewDidLoad(..) { .. }

}
```

TinyIOC creates the instance of the conntroller and supplies the constructor services.  For some reason, ViewDidLoad runs before the constructor when I do this.  When I remove the base class definition, it works with no issues.

Any idea why a base class causes the issues?  I can logically assume it has to do with the objective-c compilation, but is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: The base constructor is likely running ViewDidLoad, and it will execute before your constructor does. You could omit the base call to avoid this and do the call to ViewDidLoad yourself.

Comment: UIViewController calls ViewDidLoad in it's constructor?  BaseUIViewController only calls some internal methods for setting default styles, etc.  BaseUIViewController doesn't call ViewDidLoad directly...

Comment: Are you sure? Not to doubt you, it's just the only logical thing I can surmise.

Comment: I'm 100% sure; I coded it :-)

Comment: If you access the `View` property in a controller in any way `ViewDidLoad` will run. Are you accessing that by chance?

Comment: yes, then that would be it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't touch the Controller's View property in the constructor as this will trigger ViewDidLoad.